# How to handle dynamic columns for CSV file using Import-csv in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

CSV file does not have headers, Column may differ each time.
I want to compare with first column of csv file, but while exporting I would display the full row.

```
$getErrorCodes= {102,103}

CSV FILE( No headers)
101,101,101
102,102,102
```

Here is my code

```
Import-Csv $CSVFile -Header col1 | Where-Object {!($getErrorCodes.Contains($_.col1)) } | Export-Csv "resultfile.csv"

Current output
101

Expected output
101,101,101
```

Comment: [1] your posted code is incomplete. please, add the missing `$getErrorCodes` or otherwise change your code so that it works. [2] are the delimiters really `|` ... if so, your import & export are wrong.

Comment: No, my csv delimiters is comma (",")

Comment: thank you for foxing that. [*grin*] now ... please fix your code so that it works. it fails right now since you have no value set for `$getErrorCodes`.

Comment: `$getErrorCodes= {102,103}` makes a scriptblock, not a hashtable.. A scriptblock does not have a method `Contains()`

Comment: $getErrorCodes , it hash table, for question purpose i written like this. Sorry for that.
For dynamic header i can use like  $Header = "Col1","Col2","Col3" , i will dynamically generate the $Header string.
Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic header, I used like this.
Dynamically will change $headers variable accordingly column count on csv.

```
$headers = 'Col1,Col2,Col3'

$headercolumns = $headers.ToString().Split(",") 
  
Import-Csv $CSVFile -Header  $headercolumns | Where-Object {!($getErrorCodes.Contains($_.col1)) } | Export-Csv  "resultfile.csv"
```